# Як перекласти response у сенсі відповіді системи

Tags: from-english

Знайшов такі приклади у Вікіпедії:

- [Transient response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_response) - [Перехідний процес](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81)
- [Impulse response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response) - [Імпульсна перехідна функція (вагова функція, імпульсна характеристика)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F)
- [Phase response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_response) - [Фазо-частотна характеристика](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Тобто, маємо *input signal* і на нього *response*. Мені не зрозуміло чому не перекласти просто як *відповідь* чи, хоча б, *відгук*? Як мені бути з перекладом *exponential response formula*?

Comment: Я так розумію, висновок з наведених Вами прикладів має бути не в тому, що «transient resp.»=«перехідний процес», «impulse resp.»=«імпульсна перехідна функція», «phase resp.»=«ФЧХ» — а в тому, що одне й те саме явище можна розглядати з різних боків (в стилі притчі «Слона і сліпці»; вони просто пов'язують близькі за змістом статті в різних мовах, навіть якщо вони виносять в назву різні речі; хоча після введення wikidata такого вже не мало б бути, але, як бачимо, все ще трапляється). Ті ж E2U перекладають «transient response» в т.ч. як «перехідний відгук», а «ФЧХ» як «phase resp. characteristic».

Comment: Як перекласти — поки що, на жаль, не знаю.

Comment: my wild guess: експоненціальна формула відгуку? (тобто у даному контексті я використав би "відгук" замість "відповідь")

Comment: @RomanAnanyev якщо б ви могли підкріпити варіант саме відгуку, то це було б варто відповіді ;)

Comment: Мені здається, що _харастеристика_ включає _відгук_ плюс воно ще більш технічне. Але арґументувати ніяк не можу.

Comment: @Follower гадаю, що краще використовувати слова, які точніше описують феномен. Тобто, *вужче* слово краще ніж *ширше*.

Comment: @RomanAnanyev, я б сказав радше «формула експоненціального відгуку».

Comment: [361-764-1-SM.pdf](http://openedu.rea.ru/jour/article/download/361/306): англ. «to obtain applied results, *exponential response function* was applied» → рос. «для получения прикладных результатов применена *экспоненциальная функция отклика*» — росіяни застосували відповідник нашого «відгук» (рос. «отклик»).

Comment: [34023926.pdf](http://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/34/023/34023926.pdf): рос. «статистика радиационно-индуцированных эффектов в клетках эукариот хорошо описывается статистикой дважды случайных пуассоновских процессов, управляемых *экспоненциальной функцией отклика*» — а це наші російськомовні співвітчизники.

Comment: Про порядок слів, значить, я був неправий (а Roman Ananyev правий). Якщо Ви перекладаєте Вікіпедію, то я б залишив «формула» (а не «функція»). Хоча я не впевнений, що в наведених випадках мова про те саме.

Comment: @Sasha цього разу перекладаю [на блог](https://maiachia.blogspot.com/2017/07/blog-post.html)